# How can I call a R code from Spyder (python) Anaconda?

Tags: python, r, anaconda, spyder

I have a mathematical optimization algorithm in Python and each time I have to evaluate the function value I have to call an R script where there is written a simulation code (simulation-based optimization).
Before trying to link these two codes I would like to understand how to link something easier.
Let's imagine I have this little R script :

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
y <- c(2,3,4,54)
x1 <- mean(x)
y1 <- mean(y)
z <- x1 + y1
print(z)
```

I want to call it from Spyder ( Anaconda) in order to have z showed on my console.
I have read about the rpy2 library but as I have understood (correct me if I am wrong), I should write the equivalent R code in Python.
Does anyone know about an easier way to do that? ( I am not able to code really well in R, therefore, I won't be able to translate the simulation code that I have).
If necessary, R is installed on a Windows environment, as Anaconda.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you check out `reticulate` R package?

Comment: I think we need a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to test this

Answer (score 2):

After trying couple of other options, subprocess seemed to work sufficiently well. You can run an R script from Python via subprocess and provide a function value as an argument (x):

```
def R_script_runner(x):
    import subprocess
    output=subprocess.run(
            ["your_path_to_R_source_folder/Rscript.exe",  "your_path_to_R_script/R_script.R", x], 
                                  shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                  stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                  stderr=subprocess.PIPE).stderr 
    return output
```

The R script will do what it is supposed to do. The output is being returned by the function mainly for debugging purposes so you can print it or evaluate otherwise..

Comment: And if you have R bin folder in your PATH environment variable, no need so specify `Rscript` folder. Even pass current directory in *cwd* argument. But likely, OP needs to pass data in and out.